# TSQL -Write FIZZBUZZ without using loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

Write a program using SQL that prints the numbers from 1 to 100.

But for multiples of three print “Fizz” instead of the number and for the multiples of five print “Buzz”. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print “FizzBuzz”

```
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(8)
SET @counter = 1
WHILE @counter < 101
BEGIN
SET @output = ''
IF @counter % 3 = 0
SET @output = 'Fizz'
IF @counter % 5 = 0
SET @output = @output + 'Buzz'
IF @output = ''
SET @output = @counter
PRINT @output
SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

This gives desired output. But,I am asked not to use loop,Is it possible to do this any other way? How about using CTE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;With cte(n)--this is a recursive cte
as
(
select  1--anchor part
union all
select n+1
from cte where n<100 --recursive part
)
select 
case when n%3=0 and n%5=0 then 'Fizz Buzz'
     when n%5=0 then 'Buzz'
     when n%3=0 then 'Fiz'
     else cast(n as varchar(4)) end
from cte
```

From that table ,we are using case to calculate modulo.Read out below articles on why numbers  tables are usefull and how they can replace loops..

1.http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/
2.http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/
3.https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Comment: @Zahid:I have added few links and some explanation,please go through them

Comment: thanks. I know a little bit about CTE, but cte(n) term confuses me.Is it a function?

Comment: You can think it like a table. table(column1,column2...)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using `spt_values` to generate numerical sequences as follows:

```
select 
    case when n%3 = 0 and n%5 = 0 then 'FizzBuzz' 
         when n%3 = 0 then 'Fizz'  
         when n%5 = 0 then 'Buzz' 
         else cast(n as varchar(3)) end 
from 
(
select distinct number as n
FROM master..[spt_values] 
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 and 100) A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  DQ.N,
    CASE WHEN DQ.N % 3 = 0 then 'Fizz' ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN DQ.N % 5 = 0 then 'Buzz' ELSE '' END    
FROM
   (SELECT
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY @@spid) N
        FROM sys.objects a, sys.objects b ) DQ 
            WHERE DQ.N <=100
            ORDER BY DQ.N
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a temporary table.
2) Insert the numbers 1 to 100 into that table.
3) SELECT from the temporary table and use a CASE statement in your SELECT line to print the number, Fizz, or FizzBuzz.